# How to show comment box as popup in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I want to show a view which contains a **UITableView** as top view which will show the comments posted by the users & **UITextField** along with a button below which will enter the comment & add it on to the post,I have seen in facebook app that when i press on comment button a pop appears.So how can i achhieve in it's best way.I know i can do it by adding a view in parent view with animation.But that will lead me to add more & more custom code.So is there any other way by which i can implement this ?[image: some thing like this]

Comment: use textview for your concept

Comment: I am here talking about how can i show the pop up

Comment: Are you looking for iPhone or iPad solution ? For iPad there s existing API, where you can present a view controller modally. But there s none for iPhone, you need to use 3rd party lib or your own.

Comment: i AM LOKKING FOR BOTH

Answer (score 2):

There are too much library on PopUp, you can add as your need.
the best one is -

1.https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup

and a huge library for open source iOS libraries

2.https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=popup

try any one , hope it helps you.

**UPDATE PROGRAMMATICALLY**

add these property:-

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *container;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *pop;
```

@synthesize them.

setup PopUp with shadow effect:-

```
-(void)setViewPop{
    _container  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:_container];
    //self.backgroundDimmingView = [self buildBackgroundDimmingView];
    //[self.container addSubview:self.backgroundDimmingView];

    pop = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height , self.view.frame.size.width-80, self.view.frame.size.height/1.5-40 )];
    pop.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    pop.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:pop.bounds];
    pop.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    pop.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    pop.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    pop.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
    pop.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    pop.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;

    [self.container addSubview:pop];
    [self setUpPop];

    pop.center = self.container.center;

}
```

content of popUp view;-

```
-(void)setUpPop{
    self.pop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-80, self.view.frame.size.height/1.5-40 );


    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 10, 100, 20)];
    title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    title.text = @"Choose Date";

    [self.pop addSubview:title];

    UIButton *cancelbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.pop.frame.size.height-40, self.pop.frame.size.width/2, 40)];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cancelbutton.bounds byRoundingCorners:( UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
    cancelbutton.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    cancelbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cancelbutton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelbutton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(cancelbuttonTapped:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [pop addSubview:cancelbutton];

    UIButton *confirmbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, self.pop.frame.size.height-40,self.pop.frame.size.width/2, 30)];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:confirmbutton.bounds byRoundingCorners:( UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer1.frame = self.view.bounds;
    maskLayer1.path  = maskPath1.CGPath;
    confirmbutton.layer.mask = maskLayer1;

    confirmbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    confirmbutton.alpha=0.8f;
    [confirmbutton setTitle:@"set Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pop addSubview:confirmbutton];

}
```

this is the animation to show view;-

```
- (void)showPopUp{

    _container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.7f initialSpringVelocity:3.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent  animations:^{
        _container.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [self setViewPop];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // do something once the animation finishes, put it here
    }];

}
```

call `-(void)showPopUp` method on button click or on textfield. as your need.

Comment: What if i don't want to use third party library.I want to modally present a view controler

Comment: Apple(existing API) does not support modal view controller on iPhone.

Comment: ok, you can use uiPopOverController to show pop up, and also you can add a view programmatically with popUp animation.

Comment: UIPopOver is not available on iPhone

Comment: then you can implement a UIView programmatically

Comment: Creating a view from code & adding code onto it be very time consuming.I have seen many apps shows popup on ipad & full screen on iPhone.Please tell how to implement this?

Comment: What is this **CAShapeLayer** & 
**UIBezierPath** in your code?

Comment: bro, its just the content of popUp , to make round corner of the button that i want in my app. Ignore it

Comment: did it work? check again my code added few more line.

Comment: it does not visible proprly.

Comment: app crashes on iPhone

Comment: can you please explain the problem. whats the problem in visibility

Comment: app crashing on iphone

Comment: where app crashing ? and when ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92221/discussion-between-subhash-sharma-and-deepak-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the iPad (as pictured), try creating a new `UIViewController` and presenting it modally from your current viewController but set the `UIModalPresentationStyle` property to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

Comment: what if the device is not ipad how it will show on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party libraries for the same. 
 you can have look at some of these. http://www.code4app.net/category/popupview

Personally I would recommend CTPopOutMenu.
http://www.code4app.net/ios/his-control-is-like-an-UIAlertView-with-button-icon-and-four-basic-layout/54fd4759e24741fd64073341

I have used it and it worked like a charm for me.
Happy Coding.. :)